# Alternative circuit for obsolete product

Tags: current-source, high-current

i am looking alternative circuit or module the same as DTL35A-LC. It is a analog/voltage-controlled current sink module. Its output can reach up to 5 Amps that i really need. So can you suggest a circuit or module replaced to DTL35A-LC? here is the link for DTL35A-LC: http://datasheet.octopart.com/DTL35A-LC-Datel-datasheet-165902.pdf

Comment: Questions about product recommendations are [off-topic on EE.SE](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: How many do you need and how hard have you tried to find a source of these items?

Comment: Hi sir, i immediately need two modules. And i am searching similar circuit on the web. I have found some. They are including op amp and a mosfet. However the circuits that i found had too lower output than i need. Especially some circuits are suitable for 4-20 mA. But i need 5 amps output.

Comment: My first project at my first EE job was to create a variable load not unlike that.  Nostalgia.

Answer (score 2):

In order to determine if a replacement is suitable, you need to specify the accuracy and performance you need.

This would work -- Note the connection of the 500 ohm to the 100 mohm R -- you need to wire it that way to eliminate the effect of wiring resistance on the accuracy (it's called a Kelvin connection).

Need to choose a FET that meets your voltage, current and power requirements.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjOfQb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The O.P.'s obsolete module is more complex: it has got galvanic isolation between control signal and the load.  Still, your circuit may be an alright thing to do.  We don't know enough about the O.P.'s usage to tell, though.